# How to deduce rows from a table so that they become columns?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

There is a PRODUCT_OPTIONS table. This table contains the fields "option" and "value". There are more than 100 options in the table.
Question: how to display all these 100+ options as columns + in PostgreSQL so that it would be a subquery in the output of the main query?

Comment: You want to generate an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tablefunc.html. This is an additional module.